# SpringBoot multiple module Consider defining a bean of type in your configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, multi-module, component-scan

I have a multiple modules Spring-boot application, I have two submodules:

- spring-boot-rest-api-todo-list
- persistence

that are organized like this:

**persistence module**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>tutorials</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.medkhelifi</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>persistence</artifactId>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

**spring-boot-rest-api-todo-list module**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>tutorials</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.medkhelifi</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>spring-boot-rest-api-todo-list</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <start-class>com.medkhelifi.tutorials.springboot.restapi.todolist.RestTodoListApplication</start-class>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.medkhelifi</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>spring-boot-rest-api-todo-list</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

In my rest-api module, I want to scan both modules (persistence and restapi) and I proceed like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan ({"com.medkhelifi.tutorials.springboot", "com.medkhelifi.tutorials.persistence"})
public class RestTodoListApplication  {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    public static void main (String[] args){
        SpringApplication.run(RestTodoListApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

But I got this error :

```
Field userRepository in com.medkhelifi.tutorials.springboot.restapi.todolist.RestTodoListApplication required a bean of type 'com.medkhelifi.tutorials.persistence.model.repositories.UserRepository' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.medkhelifi.tutorials.persistence.model.repositories.UserRepository' in your configuration.
```

If I remove `"com.medkhelifi.tutorials.spring-boot"` from ComponentScan the error disappear but my controllers under my restapi module will not work.

I tried many variations of ComponentScan, but with the same error:

```
@ComponentScan ({"com.medkhelifi.tutorials"})
@ComponentScan ({"com.medkhelifi.tutorials.persistence", "com.medkhelifi.tutorials.springboot"})
```

Answer (score 2):

I think I found the solution, I added `@EnableMongoRepositories` to scan my persistence module:

```
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = "com.medkhelifi.tutorials.persistence")
```

Comment: did it solved? spring boot auto configures if it found the data-mongo deendency in classpath

Comment: Yes It resolved my problem Since I use MongoDb there is no place to use @EnableJpaRepository but instead, I used EnableMongoRepositories.

Answer (score 1):

Your Auto wiring Happening in Main Application class which you have not provided as base package for component scanning. Try this

```
@ComponentScans(value = { @ComponentScan("com.medkhelifi.tutorials"),
        @ComponentScan("com.medkhelifi.tutorials.persistence"), @ComponentScan("com.medkhelifi.tutorials.restapi") })
```

OR

```
@ComponentScan(value = {"com.medkhelifi.tutorials",
        "com.medkhelifi.tutorials.persistence", "com.medkhelifi.tutorials.restapi" })
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring is trying to look for the Autowired dependency but it's not finding it anywhere.

Try adding this:

> @EnableJpaRepositories({"com.medkhelifi.WhereverYourRepoIs"})

If I'm not mistaken you need to tell SpringBoot where to find your repos, specially if they are in a different module than your @SpringBootApplication.

Comment: I use this @ComponentScan ({"com.medkhelifi.tutorials.springboot", "com.medkhelifi.tutorials.persistence"}) and It work if I scan only persistence package but when i scan both packages I got the error.

Comment: Well, I don't know what is in each of your packages, but the erros is clearly saying it can't find the repo and I kindda recall you had to enable them with that annotation...

Comment: As I see it SpringBoot is trying to locate the userRepo in the springboot package, but it will be probably set in the persistance package. To tell SpringBoot about that, use the @EnableJpaRepositories({"com.medkhelifi.tutorials.persistence"}) :)

Comment: There is no need to provide @EnableJpaRepositories with spring boot. if there is spring-data dependency in class path, then auto configure will automatically configures Jpa repos.